# BeanCreationException for Flyway set up for Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

When I am trying to build the repository module I am getting BeanCreationException for the Flyway configuration. Tried multiple ways but there is no luck. Can someone please help me on this?

Error:

*Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-21 06:11:15.404 ERROR 13480 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in com.repository.TestConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase.*

TestConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.insurance.*"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Slf4j
public class TestConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws IOException {
    return embeddedPostgres().getPostgresDatabase();
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedPostgres embeddedPostgres() throws IOException {
    return EmbeddedPostgres.start();
}

@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public Flyway flyway() throws IOException {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
    flyway.setLocations("db/migration");
    flyway.migrate();
    return flyway;
}
}
```

snippet of pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class InsuranceRepositoryTest {
---//Test methods 
}
```

Comment: Can you show your test class as well please?

Comment: Hi Andy Updated the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot is trying to replace your application’s normal database with one that is to be used for testing. However, you’ve already done that in your test config that uses embedded Postgres. You need to use `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` to tell Spring Boot not to replace your database:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase( replace = Replace.NONE
```